# Can Apple's cinematic mode video camera be accessed via the AVfoundations api?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, avfoundation

i'm building a camera application and I am trying to figure out if the cinematic mode camera found on the iphone 13 and 14 can be accessed via AVfoundations api?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/capture_setup/avcam_building_a_camera_app

Answer (score 1):

Cinematic Mode is software Apple built for their cameras, but not a Camera itself.

To get a camera you want, you can use `AVCaptureDevice.default(_for:position:)` method.

More info here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not (currently) possible.

Apple's [WWDC session about the Cinematic Camera API](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10137/) says

> Discover how the Cinematic Camera API helps your app work with
> Cinematic mode videos captured **in the Camera app**.

(Emphasis mine). The sample project for the session provides an asset picker that only shows videos that were recorded in cinematic mode. I have not seen any documentation/mention of an API for recording in cinematic mode.